# Spring Boot with minimal configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, testng

Spring Boot by default goes with a lot of dependencies like Web/DB/Security and many other things like embedded Tomcat.

On most of projects I need only Dependency Injection, reading application.properties parameters and TestNG support. Nothing else.

The question is **how to get Spring Boot with very minimal configuration?**.

Comment: just add springboot parent dependency. nothing else

Comment: Visit http://start.spring.io/ and choose what you really need in your project.

Comment: The `spring-boot-starter` is the basic starter... It doesn't include any web dependencies that is what the `spring-boot-starter-web` (and the likes are for).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to generate a Springboot configuration with minimal requirements, visit this link http://start.spring.io/

[image]

As you can see, you can choose the dependencies for your project.

**You can switch to a full form with a lot of options:**

[image]

**And choose the dependencies:**

[image]

Comment: I guess this is gonna be the best answer :)